# Questions regarding germanium detector

Tags: semiconductor-physics, radiation, radioactivity, gamma-rays

1. Why n+ contact in n type Ge is not several hundred microns? .
2. Why we require both additional p or n type contact? in p type Ge, why we require additional p type junction also? crystal itself should work as p junction. Only n type contact should do the job.
3. Why Be Endcap is not used in p type coaxial Ge detector? We shall get high efficiency at both low and high energy.

Comment: Hello, now I see you have more questions on HPGe. Do you upvote also? And do you sometimes find some question for accepting? If yes, it helps to motivate people.

Comment: I think the questions could be even more specific.  1- How much is it now and why should be more? 2 - what is the point? Are there two p-type junctions in p-type det. or what? 3- A picture would help a bit... Thank you